# Is it safe to put lavender oil on my dog's skin? If so, how should I dilute it?

Tags: dogs, health, safety, medicines, skin-condition

Is it safe to put lavender oil on my dog's skin? If so, please tell me the best way to dilute it to help fight fleas. I use advantage plus and want something extra and heard it repels fleas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lavender oil is safe for dogs, cats and humans and does indeed repel fleas and ticks. Since it's the smell that repels fleas, you don't have to spread the oil over the whole body.

A very easy way to apply the oil is to rub a few drops onto the collar or bandana of your dog. The advantage is that the fur won't get oily and collect dirt.

Otherwise, rub the undiluted oil directly into the fur, one drop at a time. For small dogs one drop in the neck should suffice. For bigger dogs, add one drop to the top of their hips or the back of their hind legs, where they cannot lick it off. If your dog has very long fur, use more drops.

Repeat the treatment every few days when the oil has evaporated and your dog no longer smells like lavender.

Answer (score 2):

Lavender oil may be an [endocrine disruptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endocrine_disruptor).  More studies are needed, but I would be wary of applying it to people or pets.

According to the [NIH](https://www.nih.gov/news-events/news-releases/lavender-tea-tree-oils-may-cause-breast-growth-boys):

> Researchers at the National Institute of Environmental Health Sciences (NIEHS), part of the National Institutes of Health (NIH), confirmed in laboratory studies what a pediatric endocrinologist at the University of Colorado at Denver and Health Science Center’s School of Medicine suspected after diagnosing three of his young male patients with prepubertal gynecomastia. The researchers found an association between the use of products containing these oils and the rare disorder, but cautioned more research is needed. At this point, the findings are only applicable to young males with unexplainable enlarged breasts who are regularly using products containing these essential oils.